# CSS3 undark image on hover

Tags: css

I have .css which makes mine image darker on hover:

```
a.darken {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #222222;
    padding: 0;
}

a.darken img {
    display: block;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
       -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
        -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
         -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
            transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

a.darken:hover img {
    opacity: 0.1;

}
```

I wonder how could I change it that it would be darkened on normal state and would be normal on hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `opacity: 0.1` to the normal state and revert it to `1.0` on hover:

```
a.darken img {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.1;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
       -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
        -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
         -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
            transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

a.darken:hover img {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```